# Looping through an array of a query inside a blade

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to loop through an array for a query written in the blade, as follows :

```
@foreach({{\App\Post::where('qid',$updt_18_q->qid)->get()->body}} as $updt_18_a)
```

I'm receiving the following error :

```
syntax error, unexpected '<'
```

The query is working fine by using `first()` outside the @foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What you are doing is so bad practice, write all your logic in Controller**

```
{{}}
```

The above syntax is for echoing something so you are not looping an array but echoing it do it like this

In Laraval if you echo an array or object it automatically convert's it into json Object so you won't get array to string conversion error

```
@php $data = \App\Post::where('qid',$updt_18_q->qid)->get() @endphp

@foreach($data as $updt_18_a)
//code
@endforeach
```

Comment: If I do it in controller I will send so many variables from the controller. What is the main disadvantage of putting a query in blade ?

Comment: when your application get bigger then updating it or customizing it makes it so difficult coz you never know where you wrote the logic but if you follow MVC then you already know where the logic is written, this is the simplest disadvantage but you can go deeper to find out.

Answer (score 1):

`get()` method in Laravel returns an array of objects and `first()` method returns single object. That's why your query is working with `first()`.

So you need to do this :

```
// This is your array of objects.
@php($posts = \App\Post::where('qid',$updt_18_q->qid)->get())

// Iterate through array
// $updt_18_a is your Post object
/* $updt_18_a \App\Post */
@foreach($posts as $updt_18_a)
 $body = $updt_18_a->body; // Access like this.
 // Code here
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach(\App\Post::where('qid',$updt_18_q->qid)->get()->body ?? [] as $updt_18_a)
//code
@endforeach
```